# How can I get a Char of input in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia programming. As an exercise I'm trying to write a Brainf*** interpreter in Julia. I've hit a bit of a block with the `,` command: how can I take exactly one character of input?

Comment: If my answer helped, would you mind accepting it? If not, is there anything else I could add?

Comment: @Andrew I've been really busy and sick lately, sorry. Your answer *looks* right, but I'm only getting a chance to try it now.

Comment: No problem! I hope you feel better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`read`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/io-network/#Base.read) function. It doesn't exactly work in the REPL, since you need to hit enter to "push" to STDIN, but it should work in a full program if you pipe in the input.

Try something like `read(stdin, Char)` or `read(stdin, Uint8)` if you want the numeric value.

Comment: Well, it does work in the REPL, but then the REPL eats the rest of your line of input. Before that, though, I can see that it read a single character. (edit - fixed interpreter shortly after, it does work there too)

Comment: You could also try reading lines into a buffer if you want it to work interactively, not sure how other BF implementations do it.

Comment: It seems c = read(stdin, Char) in julia-1.1.0! STDIN throws error!